# Defaulting rgb colour

Tags: color

Currently I am using orange as the default colour.  But I would to use a default defined by the syntax

```
{rgb}{0.98,41.0,0.08}
```

How can adapt this code so the default is `{rgb}{0.98,41.0,0.08}` whilst still be able to call `\wvPz[red]` and `\wvPz[rgb][0.98,41.0,0.08]`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wvPz}{O{orange}ommo}
    {
      \medskip
      \noindent #3 \ #4
      \IfNoValueTF {#5}
          { \hspace{0.5cm} }
        { \ (#5) \par\smallskip }

      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        { \color{#1} }
        { \color[#1]{#2} }
    }
  {
    \par\medskip
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \begin{document}

  \begin{wvPz}{Something}{2.2.1}[Name]
    C is a field. R is a subfield of C.
  \end{wvPz}

  \begin{wvPz}[rgb][0.98,41.0,0.08]{Something}{2.2.1}[Name]
    C is a field. R is a subfield of C.
  \end{wvPz}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: how many accounts do you want to use in a day, just replace `orange` by `wibble` and add `\definecolor{wibble}{rgb}{0.98,41.0,0.08}`

Comment: May I ask what happened to Veak?